# instead waiting, "give up" a task, return it to the queue and release the thread back to the thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, threadpool, executorservice

I wonder if there's a way to handle tasks in some `ExecutorService`, which instead of blocking a worker thread (as a result of monitor lock), it will give up the task, and return it to the queue for later processing.
This will also release the worker thread for other tasks.

The motivation is that some tasks might need to use a shared resource which takes a lot of time, while other don't need it:

```
if(AllConditionsHaveMet()){
    KeepRunning();
}
else{
    // instead of locking, put it back and take next task (unless the queue is empty)
    synchronized (_locker)
    {
        TakeALotOfTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to have the task submit itself again to the Executor and simply end the run() for this turn? Or is your issue detecting whether the resource is locked?

Comment: What is `_locker`? Is it a `Lock`? Then you can use `tryLock` - Method. Mind that - with the logic that you describe - it is possible to end up with "starving" tasks.

Comment: I can do 'tryLock', which is great.. but how can I return the task in a cleaner way to the  Executor? 
also if the queue is empty (other workers work on all of the other tasks) , it will be waste of resources (to keep put back the task and take it again). I thought there might be built-in solution.

Comment: I do not think that there is a cleaner way than resubmitting it. "Empty Queue detection" should be done, yes. That is before resubmitting you'd have to check the state of the queue, then decide if to wait longer or give up. I can't really give "the" perfect solution here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So you have fast tasks and slow tasks; the later should postpone themselves (re submit to same executorservice). (Yes you should use ReentrantLock.tryLock()).

Use a priority queue on the executorservice to sort and move away the slow tasks.
You tasks would be implementing Comparable and would have an initial weight of 0. Slow tasks 1.

The number of times postponed would be a factor here, to avoid starvation if the  priority queue didn't ensures that a slow task only runs if there are no more fast tasks.

Comment: What Victor is fearing is that if the queue is empty, a Task that detects the blocked resource will resubmit itself in a high frequency. This is not covered by the answer. (I must admit that I have not really an idea how to best meet that issue myself.)

Comment: with the above priority queue, if the slow task runs that's because there is no fast task scheduled. The slow task should block, not reschedule itself. My solution only has the thread commit to the slow task when there is no fast task. As written in the question. But if the OP wants an event driven system where the blocked task could be booted out of its blocked state, that's a different problem.

Comment: "The slow task should block, not reschedule itself." - That's exactly what the OP does _not_ want to do. Because the "slowness" seems to depend on whether a resource is blocked or not.

Comment: The OP has been suggested to use tryLock() for slow tasks locking, which he has accepted. Now it's about rescheduling the other slow tasks (because fast tasks don't use the lock). Also, there is a big difference between blocking and locking. The slowtask that runs is locking, the other slow tasks are monitor-waiting (blocking).

Answer (score 0):

so eventually, I went on a slightly different approach.
Instead of having the threads actively waiting, I mixed @Fildor suggestion with `CompletableFuture<T>` for the wait part.

To understand the following lines bare in mind that:
1. `Worker` class implements `IProcessingWorker`, which extends `Callable<Void>`.
2. The real solution does the monitor locking as part of the `TakeALotOfTimeAsync ()` implementation.
3. The real solution also count the number of attempts, and halt if it exceeded.

It looks like this:

- ***Workers creation***

  ```
  _executer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(workersCount, threadFactory);  

  ...  

  IProcessingWorker worker = _processingWorkerFactory.Create(payload);
  worker.setExecuterService(_executer);
  _executer.submit(worker);
  ```
- ***Worker***

  ```
  ExecuterService _threadPool;

  @Override
  public void setExecuterService(ExecutorService threadPool)
  {
      _threadPool = threadPool;
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception
  {
      if(AllConditionsHaveMet())
      {
          KeepRunning();
      }
      else
      {
          CompletableFuture<Void> future = TakeALotOfTimeAsync();
          future.handleAsync((res, ex) ->
          {
              if(ex != null) { // handle error }

              try
              {
                  call();
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  // handle error
              }

              return res;
          }, _threadPool);
      }
  }
  ```

Feel free to comment.